# CrashlyticsCore: Error occurred sending report com.crashlytics.android.core.SessionReport@

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, firebase-crash-reporting

I recently migrated to crashlytics from firebase.
I was able to test it with creating dummy crash and get it in my crash report console.
But currently i am receiving this exception when i run my app.

```
io.fabric.sdk.android.services.network.HttpRequest$HttpRequestException: java.io.IOException: Hostname 'reports.crashlytics.com' was not verified
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.network.HttpRequest.part(HttpRequest.java:2546)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.network.HttpRequest.part(HttpRequest.java:2526)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.network.HttpRequest.part(HttpRequest.java:2512)
        at com.crashlytics.android.core.DefaultCreateReportSpiCall.applyMultipartDataTo(DefaultCreateReportSpiCall.java:89)
        at com.crashlytics.android.core.DefaultCreateReportSpiCall.invoke(DefaultCreateReportSpiCall.java:61)
        at com.crashlytics.android.core.CompositeCreateReportSpiCall.invoke(CompositeCreateReportSpiCall.java:18)
        at com.crashlytics.android.core.ReportUploader.forceUpload(ReportUploader.java:104)
        at com.crashlytics.android.core.ReportUploader$Worker.attemptUploadWithRetry(ReportUploader.java:242)
        at com.crashlytics.android.core.ReportUploader$Worker.onRun(ReportUploader.java:185)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.BackgroundPriorityRunnable.run(BackgroundPriorityRunnable.java:30)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

It shows it was caused by

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Hostname 'reports.crashlytics.com' was not verified
        at com.android.okhttp.Connection.upgradeToTls(Connection.java:205)
        at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:155)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:276)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:211)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:382)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:106)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:217)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:218)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.network.HttpRequest.openOutput(HttpRequest.java:2450)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.network.HttpRequest.startPart(HttpRequest.java:2463)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.network.HttpRequest.part(HttpRequest.java:2542)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.network.HttpRequest.part(HttpRequest.java:2526) 
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.network.HttpRequest.part(HttpRequest.java:2512) 
        at com.crashlytics.android.core.DefaultCreateReportSpiCall.applyMultipartDataTo(DefaultCreateReportSpiCall.java:89) 
        at com.crashlytics.android.core.DefaultCreateReportSpiCall.invoke(DefaultCreateReportSpiCall.java:61) 
        at com.crashlytics.android.core.CompositeCreateReportSpiCall.invoke(CompositeCreateReportSpiCall.java:18) 
        at com.crashlytics.android.core.ReportUploader.forceUpload(ReportUploader.java:104) 
        at com.crashlytics.android.core.ReportUploader$Worker.attemptUploadWithRetry(ReportUploader.java:242) 
        at com.crashlytics.android.core.ReportUploader$Worker.onRun(ReportUploader.java:185) 
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.BackgroundPriorityRunnable.run(BackgroundPriorityRunnable.java:30) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

How do i fix this??

This error occurs on **motoE4 plus.** Android version 7.1.1

```
compileSdkVersion 27
```

```
E/Fabric: Error performing auto configuration.<br/>


io.fabric.sdk.android.services.network.HttpRequest$HttpRequestException: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Hostname api.crashlytics.com not verified:
        certificate: sha1/UARkLWC3ztcio6pO5twiuKzT5hQ=
        DN: CN=*.crashlytics.com,OU=COMODO SSL Wildcard,OU=Domain Control Validated
        subjectAltNames: [*.crashlytics.com, crashlytics.com]
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.network.HttpRequest.part(HttpRequest.java:2546)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.network.HttpRequest.part(HttpRequest.java:2526)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.network.HttpRequest.part(HttpRequest.java:2512)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.settings.AbstractAppSpiCall.applyMultipartDataTo(AbstractAppSpiCall.java:108)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.settings.AbstractAppSpiCall.invoke(AbstractAppSpiCall.java:76)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.settings.UpdateAppSpiCall.invoke(UpdateAppSpiCall.java:29)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.Onboarding.performUpdateApp(Onboarding.java:204)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.Onboarding.performUpdateApp(Onboarding.java:194)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.Onboarding.performAutoConfigure(Onboarding.java:175)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.Onboarding.doInBackground(Onboarding.java:112)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.Onboarding.doInBackground(Onboarding.java:45)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.InitializationTask.doInBackground(InitializationTask.java:63)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.InitializationTask.doInBackground(InitializationTask.java:28)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:311)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
     Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Hostname api.crashlytics.com not verified:
        certificate: sha1/UARkLWC3ztcio6pO5twiuKzT5hQ=
        DN: CN=*.crashlytics.com,OU=COMODO SSL Wildcard,OU=Domain Control Validated
        subjectAltNames: [*.crashlytics.com, crashlytics.com]
        at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectTls(Connection.java:266)
        at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectSocket(Connection.java:224)
        at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:197)
        at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:392)
        at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:130)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:356)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:273)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:474)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:126)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:257)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:218)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.network.HttpRequest.openOutput(HttpRequest.java:2450)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.network.HttpRequest.startPart(HttpRequest.java:2463)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.network.HttpRequest.part(HttpRequest.java:2542)
```

Target sdk version is also 27.

Comment: Mike from Firebase here. Are you behind any proxies/firewalls, tools that could block your network traffic?

Comment: Nope nothing like that

Comment: I'm getting the exact same problem, saying that `reports.crashlytics.com` SSL isn't verified…

Comment: I haven't been able to reproduce this locally. If you have more information, please share it @AnthoPak

Comment: @MikeBonnell what kind of information are you expecting?? so i can help u out with

Comment: As much as you can provide. What versions of the SDK you're using, which OS you're seeing this on, which devices (are you seeing it on multiple or only one)

Comment: @MikeBonnell added some information.

Comment: @MikeBonnell Nokia 6.1plus android 8.1.0

Comment: @MikeBonnell Redmi6 Pro in that device also im getting that issue

Comment: @MikeBonnell whenever there is a crash report to send i get this issue

Comment: @MikeBonnell anyupdate??

Comment: No, we haven't been able to reproduce this locally.

Comment: @MikeBonnell i was using firebase crash reporting all this time and then i migrated to crashlytics after that i m getting this crash

Comment: @MikeBonnell i am not able to receive any crash reports as of now

Comment: Probably best to contact Firebase support if this started happening after migrating. There is likely an SDK configuration issue.

Comment: I've also just had similar CrashlyticsCore error in my log on Google LGE Nexus 5X. Got a screenshot of that log part. Cause is `FileNotFoundException`, which says that the reason is that it couldn't find some `*.cls` file. It happened exactly after my app was killed because of low memory.

Comment: Just run into this issue and it turned out Crashlytics is down today. See https://status.firebase.google.com/. I tried to switch from Sentry to Crashlytics (started more than a week ago). All I got is error messages so far. The Firebase console can't even load the Crashlytics view "There was an error loading your Crashlytics data". Because there was an outage when I started, I waited some time before I tried again, but today it's just a different error message :D

Answer (score 0):

I don't know who this may help, but in my case, I got the same error because my `emulator` was `offline` (which is very similar to [@Mike Bonnell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3975963/mike-bonnell)'s [comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52829473/crashlyticscore-error-occurred-sending-report-com-crashlytics-android-core-sess#comment92589050_52829473).)

---

Check if your `device` or `emulator` is **connected** to the internet (WiFi or data - which ever one you use). Who knows what the problem might be? ‍♂️